# Chart.js returns a console error and does not display the chart when using variables as data input

Tags: chart.js

I am using Chart.js. The chart displayed correctly when I used set values. However, when I used variables the chart did not display and there were errors in the console. I do not understand the error messages.

The chart is:

```
function showChart(chartName, xAxis, yAxis){
    alert("chartName: " + chartName);
    alert("xAxis: " + xAxis);
    alert("yAxis: " + yAxis);
    //Charts
    //Select the chart element
    const ctx = document.getElementById("chart").getContext('2d');
    //Create a new chart instance using ChartJs and give it the properties we need such as the
    //type of chart, data we want to use and other options that will help us customise the chart.
    const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
//          labels: ["20/04/2021", "27/04/2021", "04/05/2021", "11/05/2021", "18/05/2021", "25/05/2021", "01/06/2021"],
            labels: xAxis,
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Speed - km/h',
//              label: chartName,
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(161, 198, 247, 1)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(47, 128, 237)',
//              data: [4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13],
                data: yAxis,
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true,
                    }
                }]
            }
        },
    });
}
```

xAxis is ['2021-07-03', '2021-07-05' ] and yAxis is [5, 6 ].

Console log:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object.defineProperty called on non-object
    at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)
    at listenArrayEvents (Chart.js:4785)
    at ChartElement.buildOrUpdateElements (Chart.js:4965)
    at Chart.<anonymous> (Chart.js:4211)
    at Object.each (Chart.js:9899)
    at Chart.update (Chart.js:4210)
    at Chart.construct (Chart.js:3944)
    at new Chart (Chart.js:6215)
    at showChart (exerciseOverview.js:468)
    at Object.<anonymous> (exerciseOverview.js:454)
2Chart.js:5880 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'skip' of undefined
    at parseVisibleItems (Chart.js:5880)
    at getIntersectItems (Chart.js:5896)
    at indexMode (Chart.js:5958)
    at Chart.getElementsAtEventForMode (Chart.js:4494)
    at Chart.handleEvent (Chart.js:4722)
    at Chart.eventHandler (Chart.js:4672)
    at listener (Chart.js:4609)
    at HTMLCanvasElement.proxies.<computed> (Chart.js:10917)
Chart.js:4785 Uncaught TypeError: Object.defineProperty called on non-object
    at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)
    at listenArrayEvents (Chart.js:4785)
    at ChartElement.buildOrUpdateElements (Chart.js:4965)
    at Chart.<anonymous> (Chart.js:4211)
    at Object.each (Chart.js:9899)
    at Chart.update (Chart.js:4210)
    at Chart.resize (Chart.js:4022)
    at listener (Chart.js:4621)
    at Chart.js:10777
    at Chart.js:10669
Chart.js:4785 Uncaught TypeError: Object.defineProperty called on non-object
    at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)
    at listenArrayEvents (Chart.js:4785)
    at ChartElement.buildOrUpdateElements (Chart.js:4965)
    at Chart.<anonymous> (Chart.js:4211)
    at Object.each (Chart.js:9899)
    at Chart.update (Chart.js:4210)
    at Chart.construct (Chart.js:3944)
    at new Chart (Chart.js:6215)
    at showChart (exerciseOverview.js:468)
    at Object.<anonymous> (exerciseOverview.js:454)
listenArrayEvents @ Chart.js:4785
buildOrUpdateElements @ Chart.js:4965
(anonymous) @ Chart.js:4211
each @ Chart.js:9899
update @ Chart.js:4210
construct @ Chart.js:3944
Chart @ Chart.js:6215
showChart @ exerciseOverview.js:468
(anonymous) @ exerciseOverview.js:454
u @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
k @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:2
load (async)
send @ jquery.min.js:2
ajax @ jquery.min.js:2
getChartData @ exerciseOverview.js:392
(anonymous) @ exerciseOverview.js:208
u @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
k @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:2
load (async)
send @ jquery.min.js:2
ajax @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ exerciseOverview.js:130
u @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
k @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:2
load (async)
send @ jquery.min.js:2
ajax @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ exerciseOverview.js:91
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:2
y.handle @ jquery.min.js:2
```

Comment: Please make an executable code

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi. Thank you I found the isuue and will post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was not creating the var properly. I created the var as:

```
var xAxis = "";
var yAxis = "";
```

And manually added the []. So I changed this to:

```
var xAxis = [];
var yAxis = [];
```

And just added the elements:

```
xAxis[i] = "'" + this.pedetDate + "'";
yAxis[i] = this.pedetResult;
```